# Is S is a subspace of$ \mathbb{P}[x]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Consider $\mathbb{P}_n[x]$ and $\mathbb{P}[x] $ over $\mathbb{R}.$
>
> Is  $  S= \{ p(x) \mid p(x) \in \mathbb{P}[x] \text{ has degree 3}\}$ is a  subspace of $\mathbb{P}[x]$?

My attempt :  i thinks  yes  because by fundamental theorem  of algebra   every  odd degree  polynomial has  atleast one  root  that  mean $p(x) = x^3 +ax +b =0$ which implies $p(x)=0$

Is its true ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not true. One of the requarements is that $0$ is in subspace and that is not true in your case. Polynomial $0$ is not $3$.rd degree polynomial.

Or other reason, it is not closed for the operation $+$. Say $p(x)=-x^3+2$ and $q(x)=x^3$ are in $S$ but their sum $p(x)+q(x)=2$ is not.

Comment: oh  i missed  this  counter   example  didn't came  in my minds...and thanks u   . i got its now  @greedoid